# A directed graph in which each vertex has out degree atmost one ,then the graph contains either a single sink vertex or a single cycle

Tags: graphs

I am solving a problem where I got an observation that, the vertices of the graph has an outdegree of atmost one, but My questions is using this observation ,Can it be proved that graph has either a cycle or a sink vertex in its components?